# Assign Private IP address to load balancer in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Hi I have bucket in GCP with data in it.
Created a load balancer which comes with Public IP address which assigned automatically.
But I am trying to find a way to assign Private IP address to the Load balancer so that my internal network (VPC) uses services from Load balancer.

I have checked with GCP Documentation, but it says IT CAN'T due to limitations in Load Balancer Service(by design).

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: As the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#internal_https_load_balancing) points out, Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing enables you to load balance TCP/UDP traffic behind a private load balancing IP address that is accessible only to your internal virtual machine instances. Use Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing to configure an Internal Load Balancing IP address to act as the frontend to your private backend instances. You use only internal IP addresses for your load balanced service. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: When you reference documentation, show the link. That might indicate that you are referencing the wrong documentation. In your case you are trying to use the wrong load balancer type. HTTP(S) Load Balancers are public, therefore have public IP addresses. Use an Internal Load Balancer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you would like to assign a private IP to your Load Balancer, then you can use one of the two **[types of Internal Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#types_of_cloud_load_balancing)**. More info can be found on the links below:

As per **[Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#internal_tcpudp_load_balancing):**

### Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing

> Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing enables you to load balance TCP/UDP traffic behind a private load balancing IP address that is accessible only to your internal virtual machine instances. Use Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing to configure an Internal Load Balancing IP address to act as the frontend to your private backend instances. You use only internal IP addresses for your load balanced service.

This is the **[document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/setting-up-internal)** for **Setting Up Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing**.

---

As per **[Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#internal_https_load_balancing)**:

### Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing

> The internal HTTP(S) load balancer performs proxy-based load balancing of Layer 7 application data that you specify with URL maps. It uses a private IP address that acts as the frontend to your backend instances.

This is the **[document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-l7-internal)** for **Setting Up Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually away from standard GCP services setting up HAPROXY on an instance on the vpc.
See HAPROXY starter guide http://www.haproxy.org/#docs